# Is there a way to call a recursive function from a Vue.js Mixin?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recursion, mixins

I have a search function that works fine on its own. Its purpose is to search for a key in a JSON object and get the value of it.

```
function findVal(object, key) {
var value;
Object.keys(object).some(function(k) {
    if (k === key) {
        value = object[k];
        return true;
    }
    if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
        value = findVal(object[k], key);
        return value !== undefined;
    }
});
return value;
}

var object =  { photo: { progress: 20 }};
console.log(findVal(object, 'progress'));

// Output 20
```

However, when I moved this to a mixin it no longer works. The error states that my function is undefined where I make my recursive call.

**Mixin.js**

```
const MyMixin = { 
   findVal(object, key) {
   var value;
   Object.keys(object).some(function(k) {
      if (k === key) {
        value = object[k];
        return true;
      }
      if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {

        // ERROR OF UNDEFINED RETURNED HERE
        value = findVal(object[k], key);
        return value !== undefined;
      }
  });
  return value;
  }
}

var object =  { photo: { progress: 20 }};
console.log(findVal(object, 'progress'));
```

**Template.vue**

```
// Import Mixins

onClick(data) { 
    console.log(this.findVal(data, key))
}
```

Comment: based on the code you posted: you are not `export`ing the mixin function; you do not set if it's a `computed` property, a `method` or something else. Please show how you import the mixin, how you export your function, etc. Please also state if you use Vue2 or Vue3 - that can make a difference.

Comment: And as a mixin "becomes part of the SFC", you'd need to call that function inside your function with a `this` (`this.findVal`) - but then again, the context of `this` would change with iterations, so I suggest that you should place it outside of the component, and call it with a set arguments and just return the results